# deriving inverse of Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to derive the inverse of the laplace transform myself, but I'm immediately stuck.

The laplace transform is:
$$\mathcal L[f(t)](s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

Intuitively, my first attempt would be to get rid of the integral with respect to $t$, by taking the derivative:
$$\frac{d \mathcal L[f(t)](s)}{dt}=e^{-st}f(t), \text{or something...}$$

But this doesn't work, because the integral is not a function of $t$, since it is definite.

**Can someone give me a hint on how to solve it, or a possible misconception that** **I may have?**

Comment: Are you try to get the inverse result for a particular function by the inverse theorem, or you want to prove the inverse theorem? As the proof of the inverse theorem is never about algebraic operations, it's very involving.

Comment: I'm trying to derive the general formula for the inverse of the laplace transform.

Comment: Maybe you could check out this [doc](http://math.sun.ac.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Hons-Projek.pdf)